# Calculate probability of flipping coins with probabilities dependent on previous results

Tags: probability, dice, programming, dynamic-programming

Let's say I have a biased coin that has a probability of 0.2 for heads and 0.8 for tails. If you flip it 6 times without getting a heads however, the probability of heads increases by 0.2 per non-heads flip afterwards, so the 7th flip without heads will have a probability of 0.4 for heads and 0.6 for tails, the 8th flip will have a probability of 0.6 for heads, and the 10th flip will have a guaranteed chance for heads. If you get heads at any point, the probability resets back to 0.2, and you would have to roll 6 tails again to raise the probability.

In this scenario, what is the best way to calculate the probability of getting X amount of heads with an arbitrary number of coin flips? For example, how might I calculate the probability of getting 2 heads from 10 flips with this coin?

So far, I've tried brute-force simulation and dynamic programming, which certainly work, but I just wondered if there was a more direct and efficient approach. I've looked into using discrete Fourier transforms on rolling multiple dice, but I've found that the problem doesn't exactly translate one-to-one with the one here.

I'm not too knowledgeable about probability and math in general, so I hope someone more knowledgeable could offer some suggestions or insights. Thanks for the help!

Comment: How do you say "...the 10th flip will have a guaranteed chance for heads" when it is also said " If you get heads at any point, the probability resets back to 0.2, "

Comment: @trueblueanil: It says "the probability of heads increases by $0.2$ per non-heads flip", so I think the intended meaning is "The $10$th flip after $9$ non-heads flips will have a guaranteed chance for heads".

Comment: @trueblueanil yeah, what joriki meant. If you don't get heads after 6 flips, the probability increments for each subsequent flip that does not get heads such that you are guaranteed to get a heads within 10 flips. If you always flip heads within 6 flips however, then this probability increase won't apply.

Comment: The [Poisson binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_binomial_distribution) might be of interest to you.